# Multiple number inputs with different widths

Tags: javascript, css, html, input

So I have a website with a form with multiple number input boxes that I have adjusted the size of in the style sheet, but what I want is for each number box to have its own width in pixels. I could not find anything on individually changing the width of the boxes since input type number does not listen to the width parameter. Is there a way to make the width in pixels different for each number input box? Or do I have to change them to text input and write a JavaScript function to only accept numbers?

Comment: Can you pst your code please.

Comment: Setting their widths in css works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/buwsu9pc/, you need to show the code you are experiencing the problem with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is very broad, I put together a fiddle showing the 3 common ways I select input elements on "my" pages, this is highly opinionated so there will be multiple different answers, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5f3pbg8b/3/

And as a quick reference, w3fools has a good list of selectors http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

html example 1

```
<h4>
With classes best option
</h4>
<input type="text" class="input1"/>
<input type="text" class="input2"/>
<input type="text" class="input3"/>
<input type="text" class="input4"/>
<input type="text" class="input5"/>
```

CSS example 1

```
.input1{width: 50px; background: yellow;}
.input2{width: 100px; background: yellow;}
.input3{width: 150px; background: yellow;}
.input4{width: 200px; background: yellow;}
.input5{width: 250px; background: yellow;}
```

HTML example 2

```
<h4>
With placeholder value
</h4>
<input type="text" placeholder="input1"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="input2"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="input3"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="input4"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="input5"/>
```

CSS example 2

```
input[placeholder="input1"]{width: 50px; background: blue;}
input[placeholder="input2"]{width: 100px; background: blue;}
input[placeholder="input3"]{width: 150px; background: blue;}
input[placeholder="input4"]{width: 200px; background: blue;}
input[placeholder="input5"]{width: 250px; background: blue;}
```

HTML example 3

```
<h4>
With nth-child selector
</h4>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
```

CSS example 3

```
input:nth-child(14) {
    width: 50px;
    background: #ff0000;
}
input:nth-child(15) {
    width: 100px;
    background: #ff0000;
}
input:nth-child(16) {
    width: 150px;
    background: #ff0000;
}
input:nth-child(17) {
    width: 200px;
    background: #ff0000;
}
input:nth-child(18) {
    width: 250px;
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Using class to link it to the css is all I needed thank you!

Comment: @user6383357 well now you have multiple options :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width to a number input field. If you want to individually set input boxes it's good to give them ids like that:

```
<input id="two" type="number"/>
```

If you want to select a certain n-th input box you can use a css selector like this:

```
input[type="number"]:nth-child(3)
```

If you want to see all this in action check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r9L56ucs/).